# Get info about a YouTube video

Tags: ios, youtube

I'm looking to get the title and duration of a YouTube video and display it within my app. I want to do this dynamically since there will be several videos and they will change. I've looked for a URL that provides this information, but I've had no luck. Does anyone know a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the Youtube API, details on how to do this for a single video are here:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_video_entries

Here's the URL to get the API data for Friday:

https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/kfVsfOSbJY0?v=2

Comment: Wow I can't believe I did not find that. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Is there a way to make the GData client compatible with ARC?